# What is this wordswag font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Does anyone know which font is this? It's used in lumber jack style in wordswag.

[image]

Comment: thanks. yeah i tried WTF machine. but it didn't give me the  correct answer. by the way it doesn't look like Gazz Regular either

Comment: @user287001 please leave answers as answers. That way as is the case here people can vote and comment on your answer. On a side note, Sanjan -- user287001 won't get a notified that you replied to them unless you mention them using @ followed by name.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. it is called Saltash Rough : [Saltash-Rough.otf](https://www.whatfontis.com/Saltash-Rough-otf-400.font)